# How to check if a container is suitable as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash, key

Keys of dictionaries must be hashable. Therefore `list` and `dict` are inappropriate.

However `tuple` is hashable, but fails as a key if any of its elements is not.

**Is there another way than catching the exception to check if a container is suitable as a key?**

```
def is_hashable(obj):
    try:
        hash(obj)            # this will throw an exception if 'obj' is not hashable
        return True
    except TypeError as err:
        return False

t1 = ("a", "b", "c")
is_hashable(t1)              # True

t2 = ("a", {"b":2}, {"c":3})
is_hashable(t2)              # False
```

Comment: I like your method.

Comment: @101: While it would work, obviously, using it in a function like this just adds overhead to something that's built-in. Besides, type-checking using a function like this (or the built-in one) is unpythonic. The recommended way to do it is to catch exceptions via `try/except` anywhere you need to deal with them—not buried in a function to essentially hide them (and needs to always be called it first).